# How do I print existing profiles created by the user? Any tips on switching between two profiles created by the user as well?

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Profiles
{
   private Scanner sc;
   private Profile[] profiles;
   private int idx; // master index of profiles array
   private int nop; //number of profiles
public Profiles()
{
   sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   idx = -1;
   nop = 0;
   profiles = new Profile[3];
}
public void createProfile(String first,String last,int age)
{
    if(idx<profiles.length-1)
    {
        Profile p = new Profile(first,last,age);
        idx++;
        profiles[idx] = p;
        nop++;
        Util.print("Profile has been created\n");
    }
    else
    {
        Util.print("No room to create a new profile\n");
    }
}
```

So far, the user can create profiles. But now lies my problem...

```
public void switchProfile()
{
  if(nop==0)
  {
    Util.print("Unable to switch profiles");
    return;
  }else
   {
   //print the idx and all profiles that currently exist <--not sure how to do this
   //accept a profile idx that the user chooses (use Scanner to get user input)
   //set idx to the input (this will direct the user to the profile idx they chose)
   }
}
```

After the else statement, Im struggling to come up with a way to print the current profiles that exist.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe something like `for (Profile p : profiles) {System.out.println("Name = %s %s , age %d\n", p.getFirstName, p.getLastName(), p.getAge);`?

Comment: As a matter of general style, I would recommend against using the variable name `nop` for "number of profiles", since [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) has a far more common meaning of "No operation" from assembly code. Instead, I would recommend the still-short but unambiguous name `numProfiles`.

Comment: Where is the `profiles`  variable declared? Where is the code calling these methods? How are you using them?

Comment: Looking back, I retract my previous recommendation and now suggest something more like `for(int px=0; px < idx; ++px) System.printf("%s %s %d\n", profiles[px].getFirstName(), profiles[px].getLastName(), profiles[px].getAge);`

Comment: oops, forgot to include: private Profile[] profiles;  @cricket

Comment: @cricket_007 yep.  I fixed it.

Comment: idk why i forgot to include this as well but: idx = -1; nop = 0; profiles = new Profile[3]; Ill fix up the post a bit

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down into steps.

- Print the array with an index.
- Ask for input
- process the input

```
System.out.println("Pick a profile");
for (int i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d : %s\n", i, profiles[i].getName());
} 

int next = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
if (next < profiles.length && next >= 0) {
    idx = next;
} else {
  // invalid index 
}
```

If you call the add profile method after doing this, though, you'll end up overwriting data in the array

To avoid that, you'll need to add profiles to only null positions in the array